# Trying to build a deep learning model using that plays google dinosaur on its own. It is always predicting the same class

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

[Here](https://github.com/ragvri/GoogleDinosaur_CNN) is the github link to the code. Basically, I generated training and test images.

The training images consists pictures where the dinosaur jumped and also the pictures where the dinosaur did not jump in 2 separate directories. Then I made a simple sequential model in keras consisting of 2 convolutional layers and trained it on my data.

However, when I test it on my test image, everytime, it predicts the same class.

`print(model.predict_proba(x)` always gives 0. I can't seem to figure out the cause.

Please help me resolve this issue.

PS: I know it has already been done by many. However I wanted to try doing so on my own.

Comment: and before testing - what was **training** accuracy/loss? It seems like you train extremely shortly (?) 2 * 200 / 16 steps? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah the accuracy on the training data was 70%. I am training for very short time so that once it "works correctly", I can increase the number of epochs

Comment: It might be the issue - just train longer, 70% train is extremely weak model, it can do nearly arbitrary stuff during testing. Also, you test on barely few test images in yoru code - do proper testing on **all** of them.

Comment: I feel a sample of approximately 300 images is fine. Also even if the sample is small, still the model shouldn't output one class with 100% probability